# When I click the dark mode button, I want to apply the dark mode to the iframe tag as well

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently I am studying the dark mode function.

I have a question while studying the dark mode feature.

Clicking the dark mode button changes other tags, but not the iframe tag.

I want to apply dark mode to iframe tag as well.

What should I do?

The source below is the source in the file.

**01. file : index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        iframe {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .layout-01 {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding:10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            background: var(--bg-color);
            color: var(--font-color);
        }
        .iframe-layout {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            background: var(--bg-color);
            color: var(--font-color);
        }
        .iframe-layout iframe html p {
            color: var(--font-color);
        }
        :root {
            --bg-color: #fff;
            --font-color: #000;
        }
        html.darkmode:root {
            --bg-color: #000;
            --font-color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button onClick="userTheme(true);">Toogle Theme</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function userTheme(toggle = false) {
            let userMode = localStorage.userThemeMode || 'auto';
            const osMode = !!window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? 'dark' : 'light';
            if(toggle) {
                switch(userMode) {
                    case 'auto':
                        userMode = 'dark'; break;
                    case 'dark':
                        userMode = 'light'; break;
                    default:
                        userMode = 'auto';
                }
                localStorage.userThemeMode = userMode;
            }
            console.log(`current mode : ${userMode}`);
            window.__THEME_MODE = userMode === 'auto' ? osMode : userMode;
            document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList[window.__THEME_MODE === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove']('darkmode');
            //document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].classList[window.__THEME_MODE === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove']('darkmode');
        }
        if (!!window.matchMedia) {
            ['light', 'dark'].forEach(mode => {
                window.matchMedia(`(prefers-color-scheme: ${mode})`).addListener(e => {
                    if(!!e.matches) {
                        userTheme();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        userTheme();
    </script>

    <div>
        <div class="layout-01">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div i="iframe-layout">
            <iframe src="test.html" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" seamless></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**02. test.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        iframe {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .layout-01 {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding:10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            background: var(--bg-color);
            color: var(--font-color);
        }
        .iframe-layout {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            background: var(--bg-color);
            color: var(--font-color);
        }
        .iframe-layout iframe html p {
            color: var(--font-color);
        }
        :root {
            --bg-color: #fff;
            --font-color: #000;
        }
        html.darkmode:root {
            --bg-color: #000;
            --font-color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button onClick="userTheme(true);">Toogle Theme</button>
    </div>


    <script>
        function userTheme(toggle = false) {
            let userMode = localStorage.userThemeMode || 'auto';
            const osMode = !!window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? 'dark' : 'light';
            if(toggle) {
                switch(userMode) {
                    case 'auto':
                        userMode = 'dark'; break;
                    case 'dark':
                        userMode = 'light'; break;
                    default:
                        userMode = 'auto';
                }
                localStorage.userThemeMode = userMode;
            }
            console.log(`current mode : ${userMode}`);
            window.__THEME_MODE = userMode === 'auto' ? osMode : userMode;
            document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList[window.__THEME_MODE === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove']('darkmode');
            //document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].classList[window.__THEME_MODE === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove']('darkmode');
        }
        if (!!window.matchMedia) {
            ['light', 'dark'].forEach(mode => {
                window.matchMedia(`(prefers-color-scheme: ${mode})`).addListener(e => {
                    if(!!e.matches) {
                        userTheme();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        userTheme();
    </script>

    <div>
        <div class="iframe-layout">
            <p>sdfsdfsdf</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the following approach:

1. On click of the dark mode button, change the URL of iframe by passing a query parameter. For eg: [www.example.com?theme=dark](http://www.example.com?theme=dark).
2. Within iframe, use JS to retrieve the query parameter. Based on the parameter, add/remove the css class which would affect the theme of the iframe. For eg:

```js
let theme = 'dark' //Get this from URL
let class = theme=='dark'?'dark-theme-class':'default-theme';
document.body.classList.toggle(class);
```

This should work in your case.

Comment: I don't know much about scripts.

in the index.html file

"<button onClick =" userTheme (true); "> Toogle theme </ button>"

When clicked, does the iframe tag go into dark mode?

Answer (score 0):

## Use the CSS `filter: invert()` property.

Check out

- the [CSS invert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert),
- CSS [invert summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#invert) &
- the [CSS filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) on MDN.

This snippet should show what I mean.

```js
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

function toggleTheme() {
  for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].classList.toggle('is-dark');
  }
}
```

```css
.is-dark {
  filter: invert(80%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

  <button onClick="toggleTheme();">Toogle Theme</button>

  <iframe id="the-iframe" src="https://wikipedia.org/"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

In a similar fashion, you can apply a sepia filter as shown in the following snippet.

```js
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

function toggleTheme() {
  for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].classList.toggle('is-sepia');
  }
}
```

```css
.is-sepia {
  filter: sepia(100%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

  <button onClick="toggleTheme();">Toogle Theme</button>

  <iframe id="the-iframe" src="https://wikipedia.org/"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The filter invert() function is something completely different than dark mode…