# How to change background color of an iframe while toggling light/dark mode?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I want to change the `background-color` of an embedded comments section [that's an `iframe`] while toggling light/dark mode. Everything turns dark when night mode is turned on except the iframe, that looks really ugly.

I know iframe's background-color can't be changed by doing this -

```
iframe {
background-color: #fff;
color:#000 
}
body.dark iframe {
background-color: #000;
color:#fff 
}
```

Or by changing anything in the css part and that's a sad fact.

But there's a way for changing the background-color of comments section provided by 'blogger'.

```
<Group description="body">
<Variable name="body.background" description="Background" color="$(body.background.color)" type="background" default="$(color) none repeat scroll top left" value="$(color) none repeat scroll top left"/>
<Variable name="body.background.color" description="Body background color" type="color" default="#000" value="#000"/>
<Variable name="body.text.color" description="Color" type="color" default="#fff" value="#fff"/>
</Group>
```

It turns the comments section to a dark one but still the problem remains the same, it doesn't toggle. The iframe remains dark in both light and in dark mode. Is there any solution for that?

I use the following css method for toggle dark/light mode.

```
<style> 
body {
background-color: #fff;
color:#000 
}
body.dark {
background-color: #000;
color:#fff 
}
</style>

<script>
const body = document.querySelector('body');
function toggleDark() {
 if (body.classList.contains('dark')) {
 body.classList.remove('dark');
 localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
 } else {
 body.classList.add('dark');
 localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
 }
} 
if (localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark") {
 body.classList.add('dark');
}
</script>
```

Comment: where do you call your function?

Comment: Hello there, I don't know enough techincal terms. But for your question, it's executed on the entire `page body` when  called on `body` tag in the source code

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use the CSS `filter: invert()` property.

Check out:

- the [CSS invert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert),
- CSS [invert summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#invert) &
- the [CSS filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) on MDN.

This snippet should show what I mean.

```js
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

function toggleTheme() {
  for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].classList.toggle('is-dark');
  }
}
```

```css
.is-dark {
  filter: invert(80%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

  <button onClick="toggleTheme();">Toogle Theme</button>

  <iframe id="the-iframe" src="https://wikipedia.org/"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

This question is similar to:

[When I click the dark mode button, I want to apply the dark mode to the iframe tag as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351439/when-i-click-the-dark-mode-button-i-want-to-apply-the-dark-mode-to-the-iframe-t)

Comment: That's some good idea but I have tried it already. It didn't work. I think the only way to change that is to manipulate something in the `Group description`